# What does "statutory entitlement" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, expressions, interpretation

I'm having a hard time interpreting the following sentence.

> Rogers usefully disaggregates two aspects of organization in low- wage
> labor markets: **statutory entitlements** for those firms’ workers and the
> firms’ **technological and   regulatory sophistication as well as market
> impact**

What does 'statutory entitlement' mean and what is 'technological and regulatory sophistication as well as market impact'?

I know entitlement means ' a right to benefits that is granted especially by law or contract ', but what is 'statutory entitlement'?

I know 'technological" "regulatory", "sophisctication" but I have no idea what "technological and regulatory sophistication" means.

Last but not least, I'm not sure what "market impact" refer to. Is it "(firm's) market impact?  or is it impact of the firms’ technological and regulatory sophistication?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the quote:
[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=S6hxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&lpg=PT38&dq=%22Rogers%20usefully%20disaggregates%20two%20aspects%20of%20organization%20in%20low-%20wage%20labor%20markets%22&source=bl&ots=rfZaa0y5Rw&sig=ACfU3U3IQBKr9i28vxNZEeDfIB7JLyDbmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv7Kab1NTqAhVGHs0KHZ1oAZsQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Rogers%20usefully%20disaggregates%20two%20aspects%20of%20organization%20in%20low-%20wage%20labor%20markets%22&f=false) 
Cambridge Handbook of the Law of the Sharing Economy.

The discussion is about how "the sharing economy", or informal working arrangements, affect workers and their employers.

1. Statute is a synonym of law, so "statutory entitlements" are simply  entitlements controlled by law.
2. "Regulatory sophistication" probably refers to the employers' familiarity  with and ability to manipulate the regulatory environment - all the requirements placed on them when they employ people.
3. "Technological sophistication" means familiarity with technology. Its exact meaning here isn't clear to me, but it might just mean computer savvy in managing employees.
4. "Market impact" Since this discussion is about employment in the sharing economy, it probably refers to the effect of employers' actions on the employment market.

The cited passage is from a summary of section 5 of the book, and refers to Brishen Rogers. To understand the full sense of it, it may be necessary to read section 5 itself, especially the parts written by or about him.

Comment: they are not controlled by law; they are created by written laws.

Comment: The sophistication of regulations is not employers' familiarity with it. statute is not a synonym for law; a precedent can also be a law.

Comment: It really annoys me getting three downvotes when I translate this stuff all the time and am very familiar with this language and know you have some inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

**It means entitled by law.**

written laws are statutes. The other type of law is legal precedent (cases tried in courts and decided by juries or the supreme court are also a source of laws).

statutory =of or related to written laws.

If you work for a company, and are laid off, you have a right by law in the US but other places also to receive unemployment (payments), for example. That is a statutory entitlement.

technological and regulatory sophistication =
**the sophistication of technology and regulations** [legal ones]
You can always take adjectives created from nouns and rewrite the phrase as I just did.

market impact here refers to the **impact of these firms on the market**

Comment: downvoters, tsk, tsk, tsk